# R: store different size of matrices in same array?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I am wondering if it is possible to store different size of matrices in same array. I'm organizing monthly data for temperature, and I encounter with matrices are different each month. For example, February has only 28 days but January has 31 days.

Data I'm dealing with contains 8 types of data, such as temperatures. Each day in a month, 144 data is collected, so total number of data in January is 4464, April is 4320 (30days).

I sat my array: `Brianna <- array(0, dim=c(4464, 8))`

But this will not work. This works only for 31-day-month, January, March, May, etc.
Does anyone have suggestion to solve this problem? Or do I have to store each month in different array?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use a list of matrices.

Comment: Wouldn't in the long term be easier to put everything in a single data frame with 9 columns? The first one would have date and the other 8 the data you want to store there? One data frame with 144*365 rows and 9 columns. This would probably simplify any later analyses.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a list of matrices with different dimensions:

```
x <- matrix(1:12, 3)
y <- matrix(1:20,4)
list(x,y)
```